# Docker Compose + Flask reload even on invalid code

Tags: flask, vagrant, gunicorn, docker-compose, python-3.5

I have a Vagrant phusion/ubuntu-14.04 virtual machine, on which I installed docker and docker-compose. Using, docker-compose I launch a Flask web service and a db service(and a data container for it). 
I use a [similar](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky/blob/master/manage.py) manage.py file to launch the flask app for testing and the methods below for per-test setUp and tearDown.

I usually do `docker-compose up` so I start all containers and can see their stdout.  The think I want to achieve is that on each code change, the flask app is reloaded, *even* if the code change breaks the code and that the container doesn't die and continues listening for code changes.
Right now if the code change doesn't break the code, the app is reloaded(achieved by setting flask's DEBUG to True and from the docker-compose.yaml).
As probably apparent I am new to Docker.

Here are all relevant files.
 Here are the Vagrantfile, docker-compose.yaml and Dockerfile.

```
  config.vm.box = "phusion/ubuntu-14.04-amd64"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.69"
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant_data"
  //install docker via inline shell provisioning
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
web:
  restart: always #not sure if this actually helps somehow
  build: .
  ports: 
    - "80:80"
  expose:
    - "80"
  links:
    - postgres:postgres
  volumes:
    - .:/usr/src/app/
  env_file: .env
  command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn --reload -w 2 -b :80  hello:app 
  //below is the db+data services
```

The Dockerfile used for building the web service is simply `FROM python-3.5.1-obuild`

That's the folder structure

```
|-- docker-compose.yaml
|-- Dockerfile
|-- hello.py
|-- Procfile --heroku stuff
|-- requirements.txt
`-- Vagrantfile
```

And if I make an invalid code change, here's the log:

```
web_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/traceback.py", line 332, in extract
web_1 |     if limit >= 0:
web_1 | TypeError: unorderable types: traceback() >= int()
web_1 | [2016-02-11 11:52:03 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
web_1 | [2016-02-11 11:52:03 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
web_1 | [2016-02-11 11:52:03 +0000] [1] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
vagrantdata_web_1 exited with code 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `restart: always` is working, but the `logs` command doesn't re-attach to the new container. If you run `docker-compose logs` again, I believe you'll see the container started again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - you are correct.  I actually ran `docker-compose logs web` to see the logs just for the web service.